# Proof that$\sum z^n/n!$ is convergent for all $z.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Imwant to show that $\sum\limits_{n\geq 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ converges in all the complex plane, without using ratio test.

My approach was to prove that the series converges absolutely, and bounding the partial sums, i.e.

Since $2^n\leq n!$, we can bound the partial sums like this:

$$
S_p = 1 + |z| + \frac{|z|^2}{2!} + ... +\frac{|z|^p}{p!}  \leq 1 + |z| +\frac{|z|^2}{2} + ... +\frac{|z|^p}{2^p}
$$
And doing some algebra it'll give me a radii of convergence of $|z| < 2$. How I can generalise to all the complex plane?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: prove that, for any positive real $a$, there exists $n_a$ such that
$$
a^n\le (n-2)!
$$
for all $n\ge n_a$, so that
$$
\frac{a^n}{n!}\le \frac{1}{n(n-1)}
$$
for $n\ge n_a$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $M $ instead of $2$, and you'll  get $|z|<M $.

Comment: $M^n < n!$ for all M's?

Comment: Yes. The first terms in a series are irrelevant for convergence.